# Boost::asio winsock and winsock 2 compatibility issue

Tags: c++, boost-asio, winsock, c-preprocessor, winsock2

My project uses windows.h in which winsock.h is used, and I need to include boost:assio which uses winsock2. So I get many errors that says Winsock.h already included.
I can define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN. so that windows.h wouldn't use winsock. The problem is , that I need windows.h to use it, and I just need Asio for asynchronous timers. I don't need its winsock2.h . I tried searching how to disable its winsock2 use, and I found that I could do that by defining BOOST_ASIO_NO_WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before including boost:asio, but I still get the same error.

```
#include <windows.h>
#define BOOST_ASIO_NO_WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

**Error**

> 1>c:\program files\boost\boost_1_47\boost\asio\detail\socket_types.hpp(22): fatal error C1189: #error :  WinSock.h has already been included

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Danius (the OP) points out a compile with

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

fails with this error:

```
1>c:\source\<SNIP>\boost\1.51.0\boost\asio\detail\socket_types.hpp(22): fatal error C1189: #error :  WinSock.h has already been included
```

On the other hand

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
```

Produces a bunch of noise and sets the windows version # incorrectly

```
1?  Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
1>  - add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line; or
1>  - add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
1>  Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
```

I couldn't find any way around this that didn't leave a bad taste, but this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#  ifdef USE_ASIO
//     Set the proper SDK version before including boost/Asio
#      include <SDKDDKVer.h>
//     Note boost/ASIO includes Windows.h. 
#      include <boost/asio.hpp>
#   else //  USE_ASIO
#      include <Windows.h>
#   endif //  USE_ASIO
#else // _WIN32
#  ifdef USE_ASIO
#     include <boost/asio.hpp>
#  endif // USE_ASIO
#endif //_WIN32
```

Does produce a clean compile.

<EDITORIAL> It shouldn't be that hard </EDITORIAL>

Comment: please state where exactly "this" should be changed

Comment: Put this in a header file where you might otherwise include asio.hpp and windows.h and #define USE_ASIO in a cpp file that includes the header file.

Comment: `#include <SDKDDKVer.h>` was the missing idea that finally helped me overcome all this. thank you!

Answer (score 33):

Try and change the order of includes. Start with `boost/asio.hpp` and put `windows.h` after it.

Usually the writers of any code library solve the compatibility issues but they can do it better if their code is the first to meet the compiler and preprocessor.

There's a similar issue with ACE, including `ace/OS.h` before anything else solves it.

Comment: One more question: Can an application read packets with winsock2 from another application witch sends packets with winsock1 ? And vice verse.

Comment: @DainiusKreivys I'm not sure what are the updates that were done from winsock1 to 2. I can only guess it was mainly bug fixes. Bugs aside everything should work ok, but since there probably are bugs, they might come up.

Comment: Changing the order of includes didn't really fix the problem, just changed it from an error to a warning.

Answer (score 15):

For me, switching the order of includes caused compile errors with another Microsoft include I was using - that was declaring things with "typedef interface".

Since my error was coming from socket_types.h, from these lines:

```
# if defined(_WINSOCKAPI_) && !defined(_WINSOCK2API_)
#  error WinSock.h has already been included
# endif // defined(_WINSOCKAPI_) && !defined(_WINSOCK2API_)
```

I put an include of "winsock2.h" before the Windows.h, and then finally the boost/asio.hpp include, and things then compiled happily.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef BOOST_OS_WINDOWS
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#if _WIN32_WINNT <= 0x0501
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_CANCELIO
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

An other workarround I used is to concentrate all asio dependent 
code in an XXX.hpp file and include it on the top of each windows implementing 
XXX.cpp file where you use its objects.

this method place the include asio above any other include windows.h and work arround the problem.